# A basic question involving decomposition of forces

Tags: trigonometry, physics, classical-mechanics

I'm working on an unassessed course problem containing this diagram:

[image]

The solution booklet uses $g\sin(\pi/6)=g/2$ for the component of gravity acting in the $x$ direction (which I'll denote $g_x$). By my reasoning,
\begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}[t]
\sin(\pi/6)
& = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \\
& = \frac{g}{g_x}
\end{aligned} \\
\therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t]
g_x
& = \frac{g}{\sin(\pi/6)} \\
& = \frac{g}{1/2} \\
& = 2g.
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
That seems unphysical. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a triangle where $g_x$ is the hypotenuse.

Comment: @aschepler I'm thinking of the triangle formed by the $g$ arrow, the $x$ arrow and a connecting horizontal line, with $g_x$ corresponding to the $x$ arrow. Is that wrong?

Comment: The correct triangle you want to look at has $g$ as the hypotenuse, and the $x$ and $y$ axes as the two sides. Then the force in the direction down the slope is $g_x = g\sin(\pi/6) = g/2$ which makes more physical sense. This triangle is nice because it also allows us to compute the normal force (in the $y$ direction) which is $g_y = g\cos(\pi/6) = g \sqrt{3}/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system $(x,y)$ has w.r.t. the inertial system the basis unity vectors

$$
\cases{
\hat e_x = (\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right),-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right))'\\
\hat e_y = (\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right),\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right))'.\\
}
$$

Then in the new referential we have

$$
\vec g = |g|(0,-1)' = a_1\hat e_x+a_2\hat e_y.
$$

To know $a_1$  it suffices to make
\begin{align}
\vec g\cdot\hat e_x 
& = |g|(0,-1)'\cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right),-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)' \\
& = |g|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \\
& = \frac 12 |g|.\end{align}